# MySql list direct and indirect child records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 3 tables DB schema for handling transport items. A transport can contain multiple boxes and multiple items. Besides this a box also can contain multiple items. So an item can be attached to the transport directly and indirectly.

A simplified DDL is this:

```
CREATE TABLE transport (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transport_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `transport_date` datetime NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE box (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `transport_id` int(11) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE item (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `box_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transport_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

I try to implement a query that select all transport with the box and item count. Something like this:

Expected result:

```
TRANSPORT_ID | TRANSPORT_NUMBER | BOX_COUNT | ITEM_COUNT
--------------------------------------------------------
1            | T1               | 2         | 3
2            | T2               | 1         | 2
```

**Sample data**

Transport:

```
ID     | TRANSPORT_NUMBER | TRANSPORT_DATE
------------------------------------------
1      | T1               | 2018-11-06
2      | T2               | 2018-11-06
```

Box:

```
ID     | TITLE            | TRANSPORT_ID
------------------------------------------
1      | B-1              | 1
2      | B-2              | 1
3      | B-3              | 2
```

Item:

```
ID     | TITLE            | BOX_ID    | TRANSPORT_ID
----------------------------------------------------
1      | I-1              | 1         | NULL
2      | I-2              | 2         | NULL
3      | I-3              | NULL      | 1
4      | I-4              | 3         | NULL
5      | I-5              | 3         | NULL
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Two questions is one too many for a "question".

Comment: Edited my question with sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to implement all the available relationships and then total them accordingly:

```
SELECT 
t.id, 
t.transport_number, 
COUNT(distinct b.id) as box_count, 
COUNT(distinct i.id) + COUNT(distinct i2.id) as item_count
FROM transport t
LEFT JOIN box b ON t.id = b.transport_id
LEFT JOIN item i ON b.id = i.box_id
LEFT JOIN item i2 ON t.id = i2.transport_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if performance is not an issue:

```
SELECT 
  transport.id,
  transport.transport_number,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM box WHERE box.transport_id = transport.id) AS box_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE item.transport_id = transport.id OR item.box_id IN (SELECT id FROM box WHERE box.transport_id = transport.id)) AS item_count
FROM transport;
```